# Bootstrap 3 tabs stacked only on desktop/tablet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way on bootstrap 3 to solve the following problem:

I have a .nav-tab navigation which should be shown as stacked tabs (.nav-stacked; vertical), but only on  desktops/large tablets. On smaller devices (<768px) I want to have a normal .nav-tab (horizontal).

Is there a way to do this with only some lines of CSS?

Comment: Bootstrap 3 doesn't support stacked tabs, only pills, if you apply the class you would get them vertical but the styles wouldn't be correct

Answer (score 0):

Use [css media queries.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Eg,

The rule defined inside the below media query will be applied for any resolution below 768px

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  //define your selectors here
}
```